# Where does Aristotle say it's impossible to do philosophy and its methodology simultaneously?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle, methodology

In which of Aristotle's works does he say it's impossible to do philosophy and its methodology simultaneously?

Comment: IMO, "methodology" is not an Aristotelian word.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that's true. The quote I'm looking for is more along "one cannot do physics and figure out how to do physics at the same time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Metaphysics* 995<sup>a</sup>10 [174.]](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Metaphysics2.htm#5):

> ἄτοπον ἅμα ζητεῖν ἐπιστήμην καὶ τρόπον ἐπιστήμης
>
> it is absurd to search simultaneously for knowledge and for the method of acquiring it
>
> <sup>Ross's translation: "it is absurd to seek at the same time knowledge and the way of attaining knowledge"</sup>